# Starting a Mac remotely

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Is there is a way to start a mac mini remotely?
Or is ot only possible to wake up from sleep ?

Comment: Please clarify your question more.

Comment: This is off topic for StackOverflow - questions here need to relate to programming. I've voted to migrate to Super User. (Also, Wake On LAN will power on a computer if the Ethernet card supports WOL and you have WOL enabled in the BIOS. All you need is a tool to send the appropriate Ethernet packet.)

Comment: You don't even need a tool. Most WOL is just sending an all 255 (hex FF) fake MAC followed by 16 real MAC over UDP and a designated port. The most usual setup being a home network behind a router-modem, you need to setup the router to port-forward the incoming port and convert it to broadcast (all IPs on your home net, and the MAC will find the right one)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Try google, I found these: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=886484
http://www.mactalk.com.au/24/101171-any-way-power-mac-remotely.html
http://ask.metafilter.com/134389/Apple-Macs-Is-it-possible-to-boot-my-mac-mini-remotely

In general there is no way to power up remotely but sleep is viable.

Comment: the question is to start a mac remotely not use it. ie turn it on remotely

Comment: I said it was vague lol.

Comment: i really dont think it is

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

http://www.readpixel.com/wakeonlan/

or

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050118192723153&query=wake+on+lan

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'm pretty sure wake on lan is the only option.

There used to be devices you could buy that would wake on phone call and all manner of weird things. But no not any more.

I believe there is a setting to tell it to reboot after a power failure if im not mistaken. I'm not sure if thats any help, would at least keep it on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "ultimate" solution - if you're ready to get into a little bit of electronics.

The basic idea is to use Wake On LAN, but in order to have it work remotely (you can't use WOL if you're not *on* the LAN), you install a small micro-web server on your home LAN that will send the WOL packet to your computer.

This way you can wake up any computer supporting Wake On LAN from anywhere with an internet connection.

http://tuxgraphics.org/electronics/200904/wol.shtml